# How to get put data into a database using psql

Tags: psql

I am new to databases and psql. I simply want to set up a database and insert some data into it. I would like to know how, at the command line, to do the following:

1. create a database.
2. insert some data into it.

There are many tutorials online but they seem to be referencing different tools that allow you do do this. I would prefer to not use any tools and understand how to do this from the command line using psql.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is too broad. At least you might also specify what you've tried, and what step you're stuck with.

Anyway to have data entered into the database itself, you can't just only create a database then enter data. It involves more things than it might be initially perceived. You need to have some ideas of what kind of data structure to create (field values, field data type i.e. `TEXT`, `INT`, `CHAR`), relationship to other data (per se tables), etc.

This means at bare minimum, we need a table consisting of one or more fields, then use SQL statement to insert the data into it, then verify that data you inserted is there. Actually along the steps, it's good idea to verify everything from creating database, creating a table, to finally inserting a row of data.

Provided that you entered into postgres shell prompt, logged successfully.

1. Create database with `create database dbname`. Your database name is `dbname`.
2. Check that you have successfully created a database by `\l`, it will show list of databases you currently have on your system.
3. Connect to your database with `\c dbname`
4. Create a table provided that we want `Human` table as name with `name` as `TEXT` (might be better to use `CHAR(N)` with `N` for limitation of number of characters to have, you can research further on data type provided by Postgres Database) and `id` as `integer`. `id` is your `PRIMARY KEY` (there is more to this about constraint, foreign key but for ignored for this setup).

```
create table Human(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   NAME TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

5. Check that your table `Human` is created successfully via `\d`.
6. (optional) Use `\d Human` to describe such table to see its structure i.e. fields type, fields, etc.
7. Insert a row of data into it. Let's say we want to insert a new human with `id`=1 and `name` is `John Doe`.

```
INSERT INTO Human (id,name) VALUES (1,'John Doe');
```

8. Now we verify that such row is inserted successfully via

```
SELECT * FROM Human;
```

And so on .... as I suggest to play around removing an inserted row, select a specific field, drop a table, drop a database, then start over with more complicated setup. This will help.